# Console output validation in jenkins stage

Tags: jenkins

In our pipeline job , we have few stages

eg: this stage will start the automation job

```
stage('Run E2E tests') {
     steps {
        withCredentials([
          sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'XXXXX', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY_FILE', usernameVariable: 'SSH_USER')
         ]) {
        sh """
            eval `ssh-agent -s`
            ssh-add ${SSH_KEY_FILE}
            ~/earthly \
              --no-cache \
              --config=.earthly/config.yaml \
              +e2e
            eval `ssh-agent -k`
          """
        }
      } 
    }
```

I am planning to add one more stage with validate the console out put like below

```
stage("Check Test Case Results"){
      steps {
      script{
        if (manager.logContains('.*myTestString.*')) {
          error("Build failed because of this and that..")    
        }else{
echo("No issues")
}
      }
      }

  }
```

But above stage is not validating the if condition always going to else statement.

Comment: Where are you creating the `manager`? Add all the relevant parts of the pipeline.

Comment: I am not creating anywhere else , i just referred manager in my stage "Check Test Case Results" .  Do we need to initiate manager some where else..? [ this is the first time i am trying to use manager]

Comment: I'm not aware of any reference available to an object called `manager`. Do you have any documentation of where you got this?

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/.  @ycr , i refered this document and approached this solution.
If you have any other appraoches please guide

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from a third-party plugin. And you need to execute your logic in a Post stage. The following seems to work for me.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
               echo "myTestString"
            }

            post {
                always {
                    script {
                        if (manager.logContains('.*myTestString.*')) {
                          error("Build failed because of this and that..")    
                        }else{
                            echo("No issues")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can do this without third-party Plugins as well. Here is the solution without the plugin. You can execute this at any point in the Pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
               echo "myTestXString"
            }

            post {
                always {
                    script {
                        def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text
                        if (consoleLog.contains('myTestString')) {
                          error("Build failed because of this and that..")    
                        }else{
                            echo("No issues")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am already having one post for publishing my report , can add script after that..?

Comment: @Deepak yes you can.

Comment: : as you mentioned about doing with out plugin , could u suggest the approach..?

Comment: @Deepak check the updated answer. You can run that in a `Stage` if you prefer. Also, you may have to get the scripts approved as needed.

Comment: i checked both options
1: still it was hitting else condition
2: in second appraoch , getting this error
Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance

Comment: @Deepak As mentioned, you need to Approve the script by going to JENKINS_URL/scriptApproval/. Both above Pipelines are working solutions, you can simply copy them and run them. If the condition is failing probably the log doesn't contain the string you are looking for. So simply log the content and verify it's there.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not having admin access , let me check with our team about the access. appreciate the answers.